# How late (and early) in the year can you see the Northern Lights from the Faroe Islands?

Tags: auroras, faroe-islands

In the summer in the far north, the Northern Lights become hard to see because the sun is up all of the time.

If I am traveling to the Faroe Islands, at what point in the year does it become light enough that you can't see the Northern Lights? March? When does it become dark enough that you can see them again?

Comment: I think the only ‘no’-time would be the white nights. Looking at the world map in front of me, the Faroes should be somewhere around the latitude of Jyväskylä or other cities in Finland, so add a week each side of when Helsinki has white nights and that should be the time of the year when auroras on the Faroes will be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

> The Northern Lights can be seen from anywhere in the far northern hemisphere. Only last week, displays were visible in Scotland and northern England. Although present year-round, they can only really be seen when the sky is dark at night – from mid-September to early April.

From [*The Telegraph*, 2 November 2016 • 4:15pm](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/cruises/articles/The-best-northern-lights-cruises/).